# Addthis parameters doubts

Tags: asp.net, addthis

I am using Addthis to share my videos to social networking websites like FaceBook,Orkut... But i am not clear about the parameters and the values that should be passed for those parameters fields.

```
var addthis_ui_config =
{
services_compact: 'facebook, myspace, igoogle, netvibes, windows, dashboard, more'
}

var addthis_share_config =
 {
url: "_________________",
title: "AddThis Tour",
description: "Watch the AddThis Tour video.",
swfurl: "_______________",
width: "560",
height: "340",
screenshot: "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/1F7DKyFt5pY/default.jpg"
}

addthis.button("#addthisid", addthis_ui_config, addthis_share_config);
```

**This is my Video URL that should be shared:**

http://localhost:2457/Web/ajax/../MN/Bloomington/JDLHighSchool1/JDLHighSchool10.aspx?q=h%252bbv42DLMWzliBhElDjqJQ%253d%253d

**What should i be passing in url,swfurl  fields**

Can anyone pls provide any ideas or sample code to implement this

Answer (score 1):

I can't get to your site since it's hosted on your local machine, but the url parameter should be the URL of the page that contains the flash object, while the swfurl parameter is the URL of the flash object itself. You should also provide the width and height for the flash object to make sure it's displayed correctly.

Since the video is hosted on your local machine, however, it won't be visible to any service that you share it to. To do that you'll have to put it on a publicly accessible web server.